# Parse URI Fragment in Dart

Tags: flutter, dart, oauth, uri, twitch-api

I need to reliably get the access token from this string:

`final authString = "myApp:%23access_token=abcd1234asdf1qwerty&scope=channel_feed_read&token_type=bearer"`

I've decoded it `Uri.decodeComponent(authString)` but then I'm not sure how to get the auth token from the URL fragment.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can replace that `#` with `?` after decoding and parse query parameters as a normal Uri.

```dart
final link = 'myApp:%23access_token=abcd1234asdf1qwerty&scope=channel_feed_read&token_type=bearer';

final decoded = Uri.decodeFull(link).replaceAll('#', '?');
final uri = Uri.parse(decoded);

final access_token = uri.queryParameters['access_token'];
final token_type = uri.queryParameters['token_type']
final scope = uri.queryParameters['scope'];
```